# Filtering Immutable.js List: filter vs skipUntil vs findIndex/takeLast

Tags: typescript, algorithm, performance, filtering, immutable.js

I need to filter an [Immutable.js List](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) which is already sorted. To compare three different approaches, I performed the following benchmark test (based on [Benny](https://caderek.github.io/benny/)):

```js
import b from 'benny'
import { Range } from 'immutable'

const elementCount = 100000
const list = Range(0, elementCount).toList()
const predicate = (e: number): boolean => e > elementCount / 2

b.suite(
  'Filter sorted Immutable.js List',

  b.add('via filter', () => {
    list.filter(predicate)
  }),

  b.add('via skipUntil', () => {
    list.skipUntil(predicate)
  }),

  b.add('via findIndex/takeLast', () => {
    list.takeLast(list.size - list.findIndex(predicate))
  }),

  b.cycle(),
  b.complete()
)
```

These were the results on my machine:

```
via filter:
    104 ops/s, ±1.54%   | slowest, 77.09% slower

via skipUntil:
    104 ops/s, ±1.65%   | 77.09% slower

via findIndex/takeLast:
    454 ops/s, ±1.17%   | fastest
```

Obviously, I expected the plain `filter` approach to be the slowest with O(n), but I am a bit baffled that `findIndex/takeLast` is much faster than `skipUntil` – could anyone explain please?

**UPDATE:** This looks like a regression in v4.0.0-rc.12 compared to v3.8.2, I reported an [issue](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/issues/1770)

Comment: `.findIndex` stops at the first element that meet your criteria. For your case it runs through half your elements. While the rest two runs through all of them.

Comment: Eh, I take it back a bit, actually I’m not sure what happens to skipUntil, it seems weird to me too.

Comment: I think it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array Could it be that native implementation of `findIndex` is probably written in a way that's more friendly to branch prediction than `filter`?...

Comment: To clarify: I expect `filter` to be slower than the other two (because it will need to traverse the complete list), but I‘m asking why `findIndex` is faster than `skipUntil`.

Comment: just a fair warning: Issues are mostly not resolved in immutablejs for the last ~2 years. The maintainer is inactive. He is about to add new maintainers soonish (see issue 1689)

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I am aware of it and am concerned. Currently considering a switch to immer (which is a shame, because I actually prefer immutablejs).

Answer (score 0):

In immutable, the most expensive/slowest operation is when it has to create something new.

`findIndex` only returns a single element. it does not have to create or modify anything.

`takeLast` internally is using slice, which uses sequences to create a sublist instead of populating a new list itself.

`filter` returns a new collection with all the matching elements. Creating said list is expensive.

`skipUntil` is internally calling `skipWhile(not(predicate))`, which seems to work similar to filtering.

> Returns a new Collection of the same type which includes entries
>   starting from when predicate first returns true.

You *might* get faster results from skipUntil when creating a [Seq](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq) out of the list first, as it is a lazy wrapper and let's you do some operations withouth fully realizing the complete collection.

The [docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) are actually quite good, I recommend looking at them regularly. Immutable has quite some pitfalls where you can waste performance, so I tend to look up functions in the doc every 2nd day.

Comment: I agree with most of what you describe. To clarify: (1) I compared `skipUntil` with a combination of `findIndex` **and** `takeLast`, so this also includes a modification, and (2) the performance differences are only surprising in v4.0.0-rc.12 and pretty much according to expectations in v3.8.2 (hence the regression issue)

Comment: Huh, how did I overlook the combination of findIndex with takeLast!. Added my explanation